# Binding in Procedural Code

Tags: wpf, binding, procedural-programming

I’m trying to convert the following xaml code to procedural code.

```
                <docking:ToolWindow Title="{Binding ElementName=errorListView, Path=Items.Count, StringFormat={}Error List ({0}), FallbackValue=Error List}" >
                    <ListView x:Name="errorListView" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Line" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PositionRange.StartPosition.DisplayLine}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Char" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PositionRange.StartPosition.DisplayCharacter}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </docking:ToolWindow>
```

But I have trouble to do Binding for the Title of ToolWindow and also DisplayMemberBinding of GridViewColumn.
I’m wondering how to access PositionRange.StartPosition.DisplayLine for Binding.

The followings are my attempt.

```
        var toolWindow = new ToolWindow();

        var errorlistView = new ListView { Name = "errorListView", BorderThickness = new Thickness(0)};

        var gridView = new GridView();
        var gridViewColumnLine = new GridViewColumn();
        gridViewColumnLine.Header = "Line";
        gridViewColumnLine.Width = 40;
        var bindingDisplayLine = new Binding();
        bindingDisplayLine.Path = new PropertyPath("PositionRange.StartPosition.DisplayLine");
     -->BindingOperations.SetBinding(gridViewColumnLine, );
        gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumnLine);

        var gridViewColumnChar = new GridViewColumn();
        gridViewColumnChar.Header = "Char";
        gridViewColumnChar.Width = 40;
        var bindingDisplayChar = new Binding();
        bindingDisplayChar.Path = new PropertyPath("PositionRange.StartPosition.DisplayCharacter");
     -->BindingOperations.SetBinding(gridViewColumnChar, );
        gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumnChar);

        var gridViewColumnDescription = new GridViewColumn();
        gridViewColumnDescription.Header = "Description";
        gridViewColumnLine.Width = 40;
        var bindingDescription = new Binding();
        bindingDescription.Path = new PropertyPath("Description");
     -->BindingOperations.SetBinding(gridViewColumnDescription, )
        gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumnDescription);

        errorlistView.View = gridView;

        var bnd = new Binding();
        bnd.Source = errorlistView;
        bnd.Path = new PropertyPath("Items.Count");
     -->bnd.StringFormat = String.Format("Error List ({0})");
        bnd.FallbackValue = "Error List";
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(toolWindow, ToolWindow.TitleProperty, bnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DisplayMemberBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx) property is not a dependency property, so you can't use SetBinding. Instead it is already of type BindingBase, so that you can directly assign the binding object:

```
gridViewColumnLine.DisplayMemberBinding = bindingDisplayLine;
```

I guess you would also have to specify either the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) of the binding or the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of the GridViewColumn.